# How to validate Solar Hijri (SH) date In Php / Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-request

I have birthday field in my form.and type is date string (picked by date picker).
I validate this request by

```
'birthday'=>'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"|after:"01-01-1396"',
```

But in Solar Hijri calendar we have date like 31/06/1396 and the validator say not match d/m/Y and it's say truth.

Now how can I check Solar Hijri (SH) date ?

> In Solar Hijri (SH) calendar
>   The first six months have 31 days, the next five have 30 days, and the
>   last month has 29 days in usual years but 30 days in leap years.

Comment: have you tried i think you format is wrong it must be `d/m/Y`

Comment: Ok I edit my question 
I write wrong here
my main problem for month like 6 that have 31 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this regex now But it's not check leap years
and all 12 month can be 30

THIS for Y/m/d

```
'birthday'=>['required' ,'regex:/^\d{4}[\/\-]((0?[1-6])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(0?[7-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))$/']
```

Comment: you can use this `'date'=>'required|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/'
`

Comment: why you get Dates in Jalali  or Hijri format from client? this is strange for me. we always get Gregorian and convent all Date to Gregorian.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi On that project we define in api to handle date in server site but absolutely we can convert input date in client to Gregorian and then send to server.